# Android background selector reacts to touch outside its view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I have the following layout to evenly scale 4 Views across the screen:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <include
            android:id="@+id/one"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            layout="@layout/item" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/two"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            layout="@layout/item" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <include
            android:id="@+id/three"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            layout="@layout/item" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/four"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            layout="@layout/item" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And the item.xml that's used in the include looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/bg_layout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_selector" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Headline"
            android:textAppearance="@style/SmallTextBold"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The result looks like this which is what I expected:

[image]

The problem is that when I touch one of the items / views, all of the backgrounds change, they all react to the touching of one item / view:

[image]

What could be the problem here? Does it have to do with the include?

EDIT: I just replaced the `<include>`s with the actual content of the included `item.xml` layout and gave those layouts unique IDs, but the problem remains.

EDIT2: I cleaned my project several times, to no avail. I continued to play around with the layouts, to no avail. Reset everything via GIT to what I started with and now it's working. Very strange.

Answer (score 1):

The click manager in your code is probabily pointing to the same id on each item you've included.

Try to not to use the include or code your own custom view.

Comment: Thanks, but removing the includes didn't help :(

Comment: did you also change the ids of each view?

Comment: Let me know, I'm curios about this strange effect. I saw a lot of strange things when using include, some has been solved by clearing and recompiling (if using eclispe) the project!

Comment: Yes I did. I also changed the id of each of the layouts that hold the background to be unique.

Comment: I have no solution for that, try to put a android:clickable="true" in the view that has the background, can you also give the source of the background xml?

Comment: I cleaned my project several times, to no avail. I continued to play around with the layouts, to no avail. Reset everything via GIT to what I started with and now it's working. Very strange.

Comment: Yes, very strange... so include\ now works I suppose. The problem was not there.